# read large txt file stored in sas

Tags: sas, csv

I've large txt file stored in sas enterprise guide(sas is connected to Winscp this is where th txt file is stored). How to read it and convert it to sas data as output. 
When I check in SAS community I've get the code sample to read txt file (see bellow) is it same to read txt stored in sas?

```
proc import datafile='path'
            out=NAME
            dbms=dlm
            replace;
       datarow=5;
     delimiter='09'x;
run;
```

There is another method I see also which use **infile**.

Which method shoul I use for me case?

I’ve not tried any method yet. Because I do not understand parameters. the path should it be the one in sas (in server) or in winscp?

Comment: Have you tried both methods? If you haven't then I suggest you do and see which one suits your needs. Please report any issues you get.

Comment: I’ve updated the post.

Comment: If you can see the file from within SAS EG then you should be able to open it in EG by navigating through the Server List and then you can right-click on the file in the Project Explorer and select Properties which should open the file and show the full file path and file name for you to use as the `datafile` argument.

Comment: Yes I've found it it's running since 15mn now, without any results. I'm using datafile but since no result.

Comment: @Amir I've this error   
`NOTE: Unable to open parameter catalog: SASUSER.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST in update mode. Temporary parameter values will be saved to 
WORK.PARMS.PARMS.SLIST.
ERROR: Invalid open mode. 
ERROR: Import unsuccessful.  See SAS Log for details.`

Comment: Do you have a data dictionary for the data set? Is this a one time process or does it need to be repeated? And how big is big? 1GB/TB???

Comment: it's about 5Gbs, the other 4Gbs. What worked for me is I used click button to load file in sas then sas import it from winscp. As it generate a code I used it to import a big file. i took not long time. I do not use sas lot, now I start working with.

Comment: You shouldn't use PROC IMPORT though especially on any datasets being used for clinical research or production evnvironments. It guesses at variable types and lengths and you'll have no idea if it's correct without checking each one so you may as well write the data step yourself. If you're just learning SAS I recommend taking the free e-courses on the SAS website on how to learn the language

Comment: Durinf import i"ve take care off var types, I learned basics of sas and also worked with it litle 2 years ago. Thanks for these suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Proc IMPORT` works only on operating file 'references' that deliver the file directly.

`WinSCP` is a ftp client, so you two options:

- Use WinSCP to copy the remote file to the local operating system, then you can use `IMPORT` or `DATA` step with `INFILE`
- Use filename `FTP` access method and `DATA` step that reads data lines retrieved by SAS FTP engine

```
 filename offsite ftp 'remote-filename` user=… pass=… host=… cd=… ;

 data gotit;
   infile offsite;
   input var1 var2 var3 etc … ;
 run;
```

The specific `input` statement might need informats and pointer control options, all dependent on the data file layout.  Other infile options might be needed depending on field delimiters and content.

Comment: Here I've to list all var in file? it's super large one. what does `host`  and `cd` refer to in filename?

Comment: host is the machine WinSCP connects to. cd is used if you need to c)hange the d)irectory once the FTP connection is made.

Comment: I'll try this method.

Comment: I've got also the same result this method worked too. thanks